# How to Deploy Php Application In IIS

Tags: php, iis-7, url-rewriting

I want to do some thing like below

[image]

In below folder structure application folder contain source of my application which is in PHP and that PHP code use some file from system folder.application folder reside out side of wwwroot.

[image]

and my wwwroot contain below file.in this folder I Have one Web.config which contain url writing as below:

```
 configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
          <rule name="Imported Rule Test" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
            <conditions>
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
              <add input="{URL}" pattern="^system.*" ignoreCase="false" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php?/{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
          </rule>
          <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
            <conditions>
              <add input="{URL}" pattern="^application.*" ignoreCase="false" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php?/{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
          </rule>
          <rule name="Imported Rule 3" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
            <conditions>
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?/{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
          </rule>
        </rules>
      </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

My question is how I deploy this PHP site in IIS 7 ?

Answer (score 0):

[A virtual directory](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771804%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) is a directory name, used in an address, which corresponds to a physical directory on the server. You can add a virtual directory that will include directory content in a site or an application without having to move the content physically into that site or application directory.

[image: creating iis7 sites applications and virtual directories]

[another guide](http://mvolo.com/creating-iis7-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories/)